# Splitted pages highlighting with php possible?

Tags: php, for-loop, pdo

I've got a page that gets the latest news from my database.
There are a lot of rows so i split the pages.
It works just fine but how can i highlight on which page they are?

Here is the code

```
$pagesplit = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM News");
$pagesplit->execute();
$row = $pagesplit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$records = $row[0];
$pages = ceil($records / 20);
for ($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++) { 
    echo "<a href='news.php?p={$i}'>{$i}</a> "; 
};
```

What is the best way too highlight these splitted pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get what page they're on...

```
$_GET['p']
```

Then it's a matter of checking that against the loop counter to see if there is a match.

```
if ($i == $_GET['p']) {
    // You're on this page
}
```